# How to filter {ITEM_TITLE} and {ITEM_DESCRIPTION} osclass keywords before using them in emails?

Tags: filter, osclass

How to filter {ITEM_TITLE} and {ITEM_DESCRIPTION} osclass keywords before using them in emails?

I want to apply a function on the item_title and item_description before using them in emails.

Ex.
Title: Sell bmw_ x5__

To become 
Sell bmw x5

without changing the database values

I have the function 
removeunderline(argument) that works, I only need to know from where to call it or where to use it.

(Osclass forums are blocked for new users, that's why I ask here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/oc-includes/osclass/emails.php

Put removeunderline() at {ITEM_TITLE} and {ITEM_DESCRIPTION} values.

Example:

```
$words   = array();
    $words[] = array(
        '{ITEM_DESCRIPTION_ALL_LANGUAGES}',
        '{ITEM_DESCRIPTION}',
        '{ITEM_COUNTRY}',
        '{ITEM_PRICE}',
        '{ITEM_REGION}',
        '{ITEM_CITY}',
        '{ITEM_ID}',
        '{USER_NAME}',
        '{USER_EMAIL}',
        '{ITEM_TITLE}',
        '{ITEM_URL}',
        '{ITEM_LINK}',
        '{VALIDATION_LINK}',
        '{VALIDATION_URL}',
        '{EDIT_LINK}',
        '{EDIT_URL}',
        '{DELETE_LINK}',
        '{DELETE_URL}'
    );
    $words[] = array(
        $all,
        removeunderline($item['s_description']), // here
        $item['s_country'],
        osc_format_price($item['i_price']),
        $item['s_region'],
        $item['s_city'],
        $item['pk_i_id'],
        $item['s_contact_name'],
        $item['s_contact_email'],
        removeunderline($item['s_title']), // here
        $item_url,
        $item_link,
        '<a href="' . $validation_url . '" >' . $validation_url . '</a>',
        $validation_url,
        '<a href="' . $edit_url . '">' . $edit_url . '</a>',
        $edit_url,
        '<a href="' . $delete_url . '">' . $delete_url . '</a>',
        $delete_url
    );
```

Do the same for all {ITEM_TITLE} in this file (10 replacements).

Do the same for all {ITEM_DESCRIPTION} in this file (3 replacements).